# Prove a tensor symmetric at a point is symmetric everywhere

Tags: tensors

If a tensor is found to be symmetric at an arbitrary point $X$; $B_{\mu\nu}(X)=B_{\nu\mu}(X)$. Can this be used to argue that $B_{\mu\nu}$ must be symmetric everywhere?

I'm following the derivation on Weinberg's Gravitation and cosmology section 13.4. After choosing an arbitrary point for which the Killing vector vanishes, a certain tensor was found to be symmetric then he argued ``Since X was arbitrary, this must hold everywhere''

Comment: This is far too vague a question. You need lots more information to make it approachable.  I can write down lots of tensors that are symmetric at one point only.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had the feeling that the statement in not true. Thank you for confirming that. I edited the question with more details. Probably I don't understand the argument Weinberg used.

Comment: I am not familiar with this literature. I find the use of $X$ for a point very troubling; it is usually used for a vector field. It is typical in differential geometry to use normal coordinates centered at $p$ to compute a tensor and deduce something. Since we can choose normal coordinates centered at any point $p$, we can arrive at the deduction globally. That's the beauty of tensor fields (as opposed to something more arbitrary). If Weinberg can make the analogous argument (i.e., for any point he can find a Killing field vanishing at that point), he can make the analogous deduction.

Comment: The notation idiosyncrasies in general relativity research are endless. So in this case there is no argument. When Weinberg says that something holds for an arbitrary vector X, he means it holds for all X, not for just one. Killing fields are not even mentioned at such introductory levels. All manifolds are just assumed nice enough.